# Determining the asymptotic relationship between two logarithmic functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, asymptotics

This question is around computer science, but too mathmatichal to ask anywhere else. The log is base 2.

These are the two given functions:

$g(n) = 2^{\lg^2n}$

$f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n^2}\lg\left(i\right)$

After simplifying the term $2^{\lg^2n}$ to be $n^{\lg (n)}$ , so I can say that:
$g(n) = \theta(n^{\lg (n)})$,
and due to $f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n^2}\lg\left(i\right)$ being a sum function I can infer it is "boiling down" to the sum of an arithmetic sequence, which means I can say:

$f(n) = \theta(n^2)$

---

I am being asked to determine what are the asymptotic relationships between g and f.

I can infer both functions are of the same order, which is $n$ raised to the power of a number.

So, let's say I want to show that $g(n) = \theta(f(n))$:

---

So I have to show that there are positive constants known as $c_1$, $c_2$, and $n_0$, so that for every $n\ge n_0$, the following is true:

$c_1f(n) \le g(n) \le c_2f(n)$

I'll try to prove it for the right side of the inequality. I heard enlarging the expression and finding constants is the way to prove it. So, can I just enlarge the original expression to something big enough that will be $\le$ to the original one for every $n\ge 1$ ?

And that means I found $c_2 = 100$, and $n_0 = 1$?

$n^{\lg (n)} \le  100n^2$

---

Same line of taught will be on this side, but the opposite:

$0.5n^2 \le n^{\lg (n)}$

just taking a function that grows slow enough with the same order of $n^2$.

So it means there are $c_1=0.5$, and $n_0 = 1$?

---

And assuming it is done correctly, I can also infer that $g(n) = O(f(n))$, because I have, supposedly, found a $c=100$, and $n_0 = 1$ positive constants so that $g(n) \le cf(n)$ is true.

And by the same logic, infer $g(n) = \Omega(f(n))$, because I have, supposedly, found a $c=0.5$, and $n_0 = 1$ positive constants so that $cf(n) \le g(n)$.

So that means the asymptotic relationships between $g$ and $f$ are $O$ (big O), $\Omega$, and $\theta$?

Comment: Have you heard about "Stirling approximation formula" ?

Comment: I have heard that it is $lg(n!) = \theta(nlog(n))$

Comment: The expression you just gave is a consequence of a more precise formulation.

Comment: It has something to do with the exercise, if it was mentioned, isn't it?

Comment: Not sure to understand your last comment.

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with the "Stirling approximation formula" you spoke about. But I am yet to realize how this could be implemented in a solution for my question. I am trying to think of it again since my "solution" is very messy and unclear in the first place.